# Reliable timer for a chat room

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, socket.io

Please help to choose a solution (nodeJS + socket.io + redis) for a chat room timer.

Multiple Rooms are created, every room has exactly one HOST i.e admin for that room, every room will have 500 members in it. There can be 'n' rooms at any time 't'. A room will be destroyed after 1 hour of creation.

Node server => Process room's member related data from redis and broadcast it in every room after some interval. this interval (i.e When to broadcast) is decided by an array, call it as `timerArrayForRoom1`. This array holds the time in seconds when to broadcast data. This array is different for every room.

Now, two approaches -

1. Using setInterval() in nodeJS so that it will call its broadcasting method after some time interval. Every room will have its separate interval object.
2. Give `timerArrayForRoom1` to the HOST of the room and let the host fire an event after some seconds as per the timer array. i.e using setinterval() on client side. And node server will take its action on that event.

First approach is HOST independent but it involves use of setInterval() in NodeJS.

Which one would be better to implement so that server will be able to support 1000 rooms having 500 members in it running and broadcasting all at a time ?

Which is more reliable? (as I read setInterval() does not guarantee its time to call the function)

Or any other approach?

Host/admin will be different device and exactly one for every room, so second approach will balance the server load to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` from your node server is the way to go. You already give a good reason that it is independant of the clients. Also while it may not guarantee its time to execute. It is the closest to execute ontime.

This should work reasonably accurate unless your server hangs up because of CPU intensive execution. Also allowing HOST or any other client to initiate event is susceptible to same drawbacks.

Comment: Thanx for the reply, I tested the app for 300 users in 1 room not even multiple rooms, but it went too slow because of processing of 300 clients information before broadcast. Is it really good to have many interval objects (one for every room) ? If we give this responsibility to HOST then I think, nodeJS work will reduce ?

Comment: I want to say  that - nodeJS need to do following tasks at a time setInterval() for n rooms, processing member data for each room, accept connections, add members to rooms.. so it is already loaded, is there any other alternative to achieve this task ?

Comment: OK, you want to process data on broadcast. It is fine if you have many interval objects. But you should think of distributing the jobs to reduce load. The server is the center and is the single point of failure. If you send the jobs to one HOST it can become slow, again due to too many requests. The best way to handle such scenario is to offload processing from central points (server & HOST) and let the clients do as much processing as they can. The priority of doing processing should be clients>HOST>server. But this will only help if you are not exceeding the limits.

Comment: Doing CPU intensive operations for large number of users is a no-no. Try to do bare-minimum on the server or HOST. What kind of processing are you doing ? time-taking and CPU consuming jobs should be done separate from main job.

Comment: for one room - for one broadcast - Get a list of members from Redis, loop through that list, for every member get their latest information from redis. create a collection and then broadcast that data in that room. - this is what i perform for every broadcast, unable to figure out about taking this out of the main job..:(